# Is it possible to suppress the "with configuration:" part of a fluent assertion message

Tags: unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I have a parameterised test I run from the command line and when all the tests fail, in the error message I'm getting this text for each failure:

```
With configuration:
- Use declared types and members
- Compare enums by value
- Include all non-private properties
- Include all non-private fields
- Match member by name (or throw)
- Without automatic conversion.
- Without automatic conversion.
- Be strict about the order of items in byte arrays
```

I realise this information has value in diagnosing certain test failures but in this instance it's taking up a lot of rows of text, causing many of the test cases to scroll out of view in my console window.

I was wondering if / how I could turn these messages off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. But I hope you only have an occasional failing test, right?

Comment: Occasional while developing the code being tested, but it's irritating when it many of the errors scroll off the screen unnecessarily.